# Changes policy in Bootstrap3 library?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am a user of a library based on Bootstrap (GWTBootstrap3). I would like to know if there is any change in the HTML layout of Twitter Bootstrap components between revisions and releases of Bootstrap3.X.X. I guess the HTML structure is maintained for all the components and this would allow to play with different revisions in the same library. But would appreciate confirmation:

- Is there any de jure compromise, e.g. changes policy, between Bootstrap developers to maintain the HTML components layout in Bootstrap3?
- Are HTML layouts maintained de facto in the different revisions of Bootstrap3 by the developing team?

Clarification: when I say HTML layout I am referring to this for the case of a dropdown (classes removed as they are not included in the question): http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns

```
<div>
  <button>
    Dropdown
    <span></span>
  </button>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The reason to ask this question is because it would allow to define how a library built on top of Bootstrap 3.X.X could work between revisions.

By seeing the release notes (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases) it does not seen that changes exists so maybe something is already written about it.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically the html shouldn't change because that would be a breaking change and would thus fail the [semantic versioning guidelines](http://semver.org/) that [they use](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap#versioning). However it is possible that they could add additional functionality between minor versions which could mean that you would need to add additional html for the new functionality.

If you are really concerned I would just reach out to one of the team on twitter: http://getbootstrap.com/about/#team